# In Laravel 4.2 Running A Select Query using DB::select() throwing Error on cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, composer-php

In localhost everything is ok but after uploading into Cpanel it throwing error like

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found
>   [image]
>   NB: I have written a query using `DB::select();`

The Query is given below:

```
         $general_product_report = DB::select('SELECT X.Product_ID,X.Product_Name,X.Product_Description,X.Count_StockIN,IFNULL(Y.Count_StockOut,0) Count_StockOut,(X.Count_StockIN-IFNULL(Y.Count_StockOut,0)) Balance FROM ( SELECT M.product_ID,M.Product_Name,M.Product_Description, SUM(Product_Count) AS Count_StockIN from (SELECT A.*,B.Product_Name,B.Product_Description FROM `stock_in` A, `products` B where A.Product_ID=B.Product_ID )M group by Product_ID,Product_Name,M.Product_Description ) X LEFT JOIN ( SELECT product_ID, SUM(Product_Count) AS Count_StockOUT from `stock_Out`group by Product_ID ) Y On X.Product_ID=Y.Product_ID');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to verify that the table `stock_Out` exists.